# When to calculate Outcome value in Propensity Score Matching with staggered adoption?

Tags: propensity-scores, matching, treatment-effect

Sorry if this is a basic question (I'm no statistician): In a propensity score matching study, WHEN do you calculate the outcome values (for each treated and control unit) needed to compute the average treatment effect?

The scenario I'm thinking about is one of staggered adoption of treatment (I don't control when a treatment unit becomes treated). Therefore, my understanding would be that only ONCE I have my propensity-matched pairs can I start calculating the outcome values.

Example: for Matched pair 1, the treated unit started treatment on Date X. If my desired outcome Y is the % change in a variable (eg. cigarettes smoked) in the 4 weeks post-treatment to the 4 weeks pre-treatment, then I need to know Date X of the treated unit FIRST before calculating Y for the control unit in Matched pair 1.
Basically, each control unit in each Matched pair will have a sliding window to measure the outcome, based on the treatment date of its treated unit.

Is that the right way and the right time to measure outcome (after matching)?